# How to run a Java/Maven application with external libraries in Heroku?

Tags: java, maven, heroku, jsoup

I've been building a Java application, which runs as expected when executing it locally. Now I'm trying the next step, to move it into an external platform. I chose Heroku because of their free plans for a starter, and also because it lets me have a small PostGreSQL database, which I use along with the application.

Due to the way Heroku works, I was forced to integrate Java with Maven, which I know little to none about. But I was still able to work my way there until I was able to compile and deploy the application (source code is in GitHub), albeit with errors.

For once, I'm using a couple external libraries:

- `jsoup-1.13.1.jar` – Jsoup, for easier parsing of HTML files
- `mail.jar` – Java mail, for emailing reports

Whenever the application is deployed in Heroku, there's an **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup**, ultimately triggered by the `Jsoup.connect` invocation. From what I understand, Maven only add the references to the program but does not include the actual libraries there for runtime, which I think may be the cause of the issue.

I've tried modifying my `pom.xml` file by adding these dependencies manually:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And also these plugins in the build section:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <finalName>checker</finalName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

What am I doing wrong? I would be very grateful for hints to help me get my application running, at least resolving the reason why Jsoup isn't working at all in Heroku. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The assembly plugin should give you a JAR with all dependencies inside, but it's created as a second JAR in the target folder with the suffix from the descriptorRef field. Have you checked that you uploaded the correct JAR file to Heroku?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @dunni. Since I'm totally new to Heroku as well, I still don't really know how can I check that, Should I add this new JAR with such suffix into my Procfile, or elsewhere in pom.xml?